# Python program data

Tags: python-3.x

I made a python program to run quiz where question are read from a text file, but any one can edit the question or may write the answer there.
Is there any way to prevent user from writing into the text file or is it possible to keep data in the program itself.
If yes for data in program then how to minimize the use of memory. There may be maximum 500 questions each containing maximum 100 words.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can specify the file as read-only for other users and read/write/executable for your user only to solve the problem (you specify what operating system you are in we can be more specific). If your program  doesn't edit your file it is also a good practice to open the file as "read-only" in your program (known as ["principle of least privilege"](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Principle_of_least_privilege)).
- Having a separate file is an appropriate way to approach the problem, but if you'd like to embed the question into the code, you'd suggest using an appropriate format like "JSON" and writing accordingly (e.g. JSON array of objects in this case). You can refer to json encoding/decoding [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
- Do you really have a memory restriction (e.g. is it an embedded system)? If no, this is really a small amount for modern computers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can make the text files read only but when I copy the quiz to other computers the attribute is lost. I will try the JSON array. I am on windows 7 64 bit platform. The memory is 4 gb.

Comment: Your computer's RAM will be more than enough. Best regards!